# Custom NuGet feed with invalid certificate

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

How do I disable SSL certificate check with nuget command?

> PS C:\Softwares> **.\nuget.exe list**
>
> Unable to load the service index for
> source https://asd.ca/api/feeds.   An error
> occurred while sending the request.   The underlying connection was
> closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
> channel.   The remote certificate is invalid according to the
> validation procedure.

Please note that I am not planning to upload new package, just wanted to restore my .net packages.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I could find a work around for that by opening fiddler and set SSL - SECURITY: "Ignore server certificate errors" , present in options dialog.

Comment: How to disable check ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this issue is related to your NuGet Package source feed `https://asd.ca/api/feeds` or some settings which conflicts with it due to some reasons.

You can try these steps:

**First**, make sure that you can access `https://asd.ca/api/feeds` and can get any request from it and troubleshoot the problem that are not feed addresses.

**Second**, open VS and make sure that the URL `https://asd.ca/api/feeds` is checked under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`--> `Package Source` and all the urls which are used to restore the nuget packages of your solution are checked.

1. clean the NuGet cache or delete the `packages` folder under `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget`
2. open `registry editor` and then Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client` and change the value of this key `DisabledByDefault` to `1`.
3. run PowerShell as administrator and then type these:

   ```
   reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
   reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
   ```

   For more info you can refer to [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/).

   Also try this function in PowerShell :

   ```
   nuget trusted-signers Add -Name xxxxxxx(package source name) -ServiceIndex https://asd.ca/api/feeds
   ```

   You can also refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-trusted-signers).
4. try to change to use another domain on internet Explorer in case the current domain is restricted by certain tools.
5. go to `Settings`( Global Settings of your PC ) --> `Network and Internet` --> `Proxy` --> Automatic Proxy Setup --> and set `Automatically detect settings` to `off`.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and my solution is "Download and add certificate to Windows Certificate Manager"

1. Download *.crt file in browser 2
2. run MMC.EXE
3. File, Add Snap-In: Certificates
4. Import certificate in Local Computer -> Trusted root certificate authorities
5. Reboot

---

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the two answers above I was able to fix my issue on Windows. The only gotcha I would like to add for others is to check that the entire certificate validation path is valid. This means that the root certificate of the certificate you installed in the Trusted root certificate authorities as [DMihaylcihenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62268514/5898327) highlighted above must also be installed in the Trusted root certificate authorities. Otherwise the certificate validation procedure will keep failing.